# EJS Variable in HTML Style attribute

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to pass a variable into the style attribute of this div:

```
<div class="progress progress-sm">
      <div class="progress-bar bg-success" aria-valuenow="<%=Math.round((resp.length / 14) * 100) %>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <%=Math.round((resp.length / 14) * 100) %>%;"><span class="sr-only"><%=Math.round((resp.length / 14) * 100) %>%</span></div>
</div>
```

But unfortunately it is saying "property value expected", so I am assuming I cannot pass in variables here. Is there a work around for this? I can use the same exact variable in other places so it is not that.

Answer (score 0):

I solution I found was to add in some javascript down at the bottom like so:

```
   <script>
    document.getElementById('prog').style.setProperty('width', '<%=Math.round((resp.length / 14) * 100) %>%')
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it like this by suppressing the error.

I believe it to be a false error caused by css not recognizing EJS:

```
<div class="progress progress-sm">
  <div
    class="progress-bar bg-success"
    aria-valuenow="<%=Math.round((resp.length / 14) * 100) %>"
    aria-valuemin="0"
    aria-valuemax="100"
    <% /* eslint-disable css-propertyvalueexpected */ %>
    style="width: <%=Math.round((resp.length / 14) * 100) %>%;"
  >
    <span class="sr-only"><%=Math.round((resp.length / 14) * 100) %>%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```